# Is it possible to overwrite str's % behaviour using __rmod__?

Tags: python, string, operator-overloading

I'd like to do:

```
x %doSomething% y
```

which is easy enough to do (see code below) for any x and any y except in the case that x is a str.

Is there any way (e.g. adding a special method or raising a specific error) to cause old style string formatting to fail (similarly to how 1 %doSomthing fails with a TypeError) and revert to the __rmod__ method defined in the doSomething object?

```
class BinaryMessage(object):
  def __init__(self, fn):
    self._fn = fn
  def __rmod__(self, LHS):
    return BinaryMessagePartial(self._fn, LHS)

class BinaryMessagePartial(object):
  def __init__(self, fn, LHS):
    self._fn = fn
    self._LHS = LHS
  def __mod__(self, RHS):
    return self._fn(self._LHS, RHS)

def _doSomething(a , b):
  return a + b

doSomething = BinaryMessage(_doSomething)

result = 5 %doSomething% 6
assert result == 11
```

Comment: To clarify: You want `"foo" % doSomething % "bar"` to return `"foobar"`? I believe that is impossible, because `str.__mod__` raises a `TypeError` instead of returning `NotImplemented`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't see that working with your answer. It works for integers etc., like in the question, but `"foo" % doSomething % "bar"` raises the same TypeError.

Comment: @L3viathan: nope, I was getting a little too far ahead here. This is actually a bug in Python, in my opinion.

Comment: @L3viathan if you post that as an answer I can select it the best fit

Comment: @DangerMouse I'm not sure what I would be adding to Martijn's answer.

Comment: @DangerMouse: how is L3viathan's response different from mine?

Comment: @DangerMouse: also, note that the `TypeError` is raised because the LHS string doesn't contain a `%s` slot; if you were to use `'%s' % doSomething` then no exception is raised at all.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Martijin, your answer is thorough and shows a deep understanding though doesn't address the presented problem (unless the suggestion is for BinaryMessage to subclass str). You explain that that there is a bug in str that prevents a subclass of string from overriding __rmod__ but L3viathan explains that the key issue is str.__mod__ raises a Type error instead of returning NotImplemented and thus answers the question as "it's not possible". I felt that was a better answer to the presented question, though your action of raising a bug report is very welcome.

Comment: @L3viathan, see above

Comment: @DangerMouse: no, you misunderstand what L3viathan is saying there. There is *no workaround* at this time. The presented problem can't be addressed until the bug is fixed. *That's* why it is not possible. The `TypeError` is not the reason, the reason is that `str % ..` accepts all types and will never return `NotImplemented` **and** the remaining path of subclassing `str` doesn't work either because of the bug.

Comment: @DangerMouse: my answer does state this: *This would have been the only option here, `str %` other never returns `NotImplemented`, all RHS types are accepted*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Note**: I submitted patches for Python 2.7, and 3.5 and up. These have landed and are part of 2.7.14, 3.5.4, 3.6.1 and 3.7, where the OP example now works as expected. For older versions, see below.

---

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible in Python. The behaviour is hardcoded in the evaluation loop:

```c
TARGET(BINARY_MODULO) {
    PyObject *divisor = POP();
    PyObject *dividend = TOP();
    PyObject *res = PyUnicode_CheckExact(dividend) ?
        PyUnicode_Format(dividend, divisor) :
        PyNumber_Remainder(dividend, divisor);
```

(From the [Python 3.5 source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.2/Python/ceval.c#l1545), where `PyUnicode` is the Python `str` type).

This is unfortunate, because for *every other type* you can prevent the `LHS.__mod__` method to be invoked by using a subclass for the right-hand operand; from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ror__):

> **Note**: If the right operand’s type is a subclass of the left operand’s type and that subclass provides the reflected method for the operation, this method will be called before the left operand’s non-reflected method. This behavior allows subclasses to override their ancestors’ operations.

This would have been the only option here, `str % other` never returns `NotImplemented`, *all* RHS types are accepted (the actual [`str.__mod__` method](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.2/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l13670) only accepts `str` objects for the RHS, but is not called in this case).

I consider this a bug in Python, filed as [issue #28598](http://bugs.python.org/issue28598).

Comment: Thx. Very nice to have a definitive answer.

Comment: Thx to L3viathan for initially pointing out the problem and to MartijnPieters for digging down and initiating a bug track. My chosen workaround is to use `__mul__` and `__rmul__` thus `result = 4 *plus* 5`

Comment: @Martijn Pieters
I'm having this same issue when using Python 3.8. Did the fix somehow get removed?

Comment: @Ack: no, the fix is definitely there in 3.7, 3.8 and 3.9. The code in the issue I filed works on those versions, fails in 3.6.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the reply, I realized my scenario is slightly different ( I think).
If you've got time please see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68040389/overriding-the-rmod-in-myclass-does-not-work-if-typeother-str

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I settled on >> and wrote a decorator to do this - see https://pypi.org/project/coppertop/