# Overriding the '__rmod__' in MyClass does not work if type(other) == str

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I am attempting to override the behavior of `__rmod__` in my class; however, unless `MyClass` inherits from 'str' it does not work. This is similar to [Python Issue 28598](https://bugs.python.org/issue28598) and I think the fix for that issue is why if I subclass 'str' with MyClass it will work. I do NOT want to subclass 'str' though!

Sample code showing the issue (the 4th assertEqual will fail) with:

**TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting**

```
import unittest


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __mod__(self, other):
        return self.value % int(other)

    def __rmod__(self, other):
        return int(other) % self.value

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.value + int(other)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.__add__(other)


class UnitTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_rmod(self):
        self.assertEqual(100, MyClass(50) + "50")
        self.assertEqual(100, "50" + MyClass(50))
        self.assertEqual(1, MyClass(101) % "10")
        self.assertEqual(1, "101" % MyClass(10))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

if I update MyClass to subclass 'str'

```
class MyClass(str)
```

The tests will all pass.

Comment: [From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rmod__) for the `__r<op>__`  methods: `These functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation` strings support the `%` operator for string formatting so your method is not called

Comment: @IainShelvington strings also support the + operand, and yet that __radd__ is called for MyClass

Comment: @Ack: yes, because strings do not support the `+` operation with anything other than strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python only calls `MyClass.__rmod__()` in two specific cases:

- if the left-hand operand declined handling the `%` operation by returning `NotImplememted`, or doesn’t have an implementation of the `__mod__` hook.
- if the type of the right-hand operand is a subclass of the type of the left-hand operand.

Python strings can handle *any* type of object on the right-hand-side of the `%` operator, so the first case never applies. The `str.__mod__()` implementation directly raises an exception if using the right-hand operand doesn’t work for some reason and will *never* return `NotImplemented`.

Since your class doesn’t inherit from `str` the second case also doesn’t apply.

Other operations, like `+` do work because case one applies; strings only accept other strings as the right-hand value, and so return `NotImplemented`.

If you must intercept `string_value % MyClass()`, your *only option* is to subclass `str`, I’m afraid.

Also see the [documentation on `__rmod__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rmod__):

> These functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation.

which links to a [footnote](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#id10):

> “Does not support” here means that the class has no such method, or the method returns `NotImplemented`.

The main documentation follows with a note:

> If the right operand’s type is a subclass of the left operand’s type and that subclass provides a different implementation of the reflected method for the operation, this method will be called before the left operand’s non-reflected method. This behavior allows subclasses to override their ancestors’ operations.